# Using a variable as a sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a RunTime 13 error when trying to use a variable for a sheetname as per below:

```
Sub inputdata()

Set asheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Range("D12")
Set rangeDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Range("inputdate")

Range("F12:M12").Copy
Sheets(asheet1).Select
```

It is erroring on the line Sheets(asheet1).Select

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: A general hint is to always use Option Explicit (Tools> Options> Editor> Require Variable Declaration), which will force you to dimension all variables and objects you use. If you would have asheet1 dimensioned as a `Worksheet` it would never allow to be `Set` to a `Range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asheet1 is not a string, you are asigning a range object to it . You should declare asheet1 as string and the change this line to

```
Dim asheet1 as string
asheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input").Range("D12").Value
```

That should make it work!

Edit

removed the Set keyword from the string var.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortuately it gives the error of 'object required' on Set asheet1 =

Comment: @subtilty I'm sorry, I should have removed the Set keyword since asheet1 is a string and no longer an object.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that has helped alot.

Comment: I would suggest to use `Value2` unless the cell formatting is explicitely needed...

Comment: @K_B: `Value2` is not required for string contents. Try using `Value` vs `Value2` on a cell formatted with currency data type.

Comment: I know it isn't required, but it is a faster method in general as it would not try to apply any number formatting

Comment: @K_B: I didnt know that. Although, it might not be required in a scenario where performance is necessary. Could you point me to a doc which suggests that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub inputdata()
dim inputSheet as WorkSheet
dim aCellOnInputSheet as Range
dim inputDateCell as Range
dim userSheetName as String


Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input") 

Set aCellOnInputSheet = inputSheet.Range("D12")
userSheetName = aCellOnInputSheet.Value
Set inputDateCell = inputSheet.Range("inputdate")

Range("F12:M12").Copy
Sheets(userSheetName).Select

End Sub
```

EDIT: A couple of points
1) `Option Explicit` is a must.
2) Define variables and name it appropriately. i.e. define variable which refers to a cell/Range with the name range instead of `aSheet` - it confuses the reader

Comment: This is not what he asked for.